# stream video freeze after few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I tried to make a simple app that plays live stream from a url.

At the start everything working okay, than after few seconds of playing the video freeze but the audio is still playing on the background.

```
var mediaPlayer: MPMoviePlayerController = MPMoviePlayerController()

var url = "http://keshethlslive-lh.akamaihd.net/i/c2n_1@195269/master.m3u8"

mediaPlayer.contentURL = NSURL(string: url)

mediaPlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(mediaPlayer.view)

mediaPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming

mediaPlayer.play()
```

Comment: hi, i am also facing same issue. where this it fix.